# Programatically set breakpoint for ruby-debug-ide (RubyMine)

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine, ruby-debug-ide

Is it possible to programatically set a breakpoint... that is... start the debugger, that RubyMine uses, ruby-debug-ide?

My goal is to somehow start it automatically when a test fails.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something related this when your question popped out. So what you want to do is to break when certain (or any) test fails? For this purpose you can use the *debugger* command.

Just add *begin...rescue* block to your test as follows

```
begin
  test 'todo' do
    result = todo
    assert_equal 25, result
  end
rescue Minitest::Assertion => e
  debugger
```

If you aren't using the Minitest, replace the *Minitest::Assertion* with the appropriate one such as *Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError* for Test::Unit.